# Compute the transformation matrix from plane equation

Tags: matrix, graphics, projection

I am trying to find the parallel projection matrix to project a 3D arbitrary point to an plane of equation ax+by+cz+d=0. I would like to project my 3D points to the plane, parallel to the normal of the plane. I know how to do it in a classical way but I heard about homogeneous matrix. I found a lot of information on perspective projection matrix but I am a little bit lost, and don't know how to apply that to my problem..

Any help ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you'll be starting with the plane equation in the form `Ax + By + Cz + D = 0`, you'll first want to define a local coordinate system that allows you to use a parametric equation of the plane.

The parametric equation of the plane we're interested in requires you to write it in the form of some origin `Q` (any point on the plane) plus the coordinate `u` times some vector `U` in the plane, plus the coordinate `v` times some vector `V` also in the plane, but not colinear with `U` plus the coordinate `n` times the normal vector `N` = `(A,B,C)`.

`Q + uU + vV + nN`

If you had these `u,v,n` coordinates, you would perform your operation of projecting all points in space onto the plane by simply setting their `n` coordinate to zero and keeping their `u` and `v` coordinates as is.

So we will start with a matrix that can transform from the *local* coordinate system (local to the plane) in `u,v,n` to the *global* coordinate system in `x,y,z` coordinates.  This is really straightforward to write as a 4x4 homogeneous matrix.

```
    [ Ux Vx Nx Qx ]
G = [ Uy Vy Ny Qy ]
    [ Uz Vz Nz Qz ]
    [ 0  0  0  1  ]
```

(Reminder that `Nx = A` `Ny = B` and `Nz = C`.)

Call this matrix `G` (for "global").  The inverse `G⁻¹` would transform from global back to local coordinates.

Our matrix `F` (for "flatten") that squashes the `n` coordinate to zero is simply:

```
    [ 1 0 0 0 ]
F = [ 0 1 0 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 0 ]
    [ 0 0 0 1 ]
```

So now we can construct your matrix `M` that begins by transforming from global to local coordinates with `G⁻¹`, then flattening it to the plane with `F`, then transforming from local to global coordinates with `G`.  (Remember the order is reversed for matrices because the vector goes on the right.)

`M = GFG⁻¹`

That's a 4x4 matrix formed by `G` multiplied by `F` multiplied by `G⁻¹`.

There were two steps I skipped.

1. How to choose a point `Q` in the plane.
2. How to choose vectors for `U` and `V`

We can choose any origin for the parametric definition of the plane because we won't be using the `u` or `v` coordinates.

To find a point `Q` in the plane to use as its origin, we can find where the plane intersects either the X, Y or Z axis.   (It *will* hit one of those).  Simply use any non-zero coordinate of the normal vector.  This is like substituting the point `(0,0,z)` into the plane equation `Ax + By + Cz + D = 0` and solving for `z`.  There are three potentially appropriate points depending on which coordinate was non-zero.

- `(0, 0, -D/C)`
- `(0, -D/B, 0)`
- `(-D/A, 0, 0)`

To choose vectors for `U` and `V` (they don't actually have to be unit vectors) you just have to choose vectors that are in the plane that are not colinear.

To choose a `U` vector, we can take any vector and take the cross product of that vector and the normal.  The result will be a vector in the plane.  We just have to make sure this cross product does not result in a zero-length vector.  In other words, the "*any vector*" we choose must not be colinear with the normal.  We can select one of:

- `X̂ = (1, 0, 0)`
- `Ŷ = (0, 1, 0)`
- `Ẑ = (0, 0, 1)`

e.g.:  `U = N × X̂`

One of the above choices will be appropriately not colinear with the normal vector.  Check that the cross product is not zero-length before carrying on.

Then, to get the `V` vector, we simply take `V = N × U` (cross product).  Again, none of these vectors have to be unit vectors because we don't care about the `u` and `v` coordinates and we don't care about the magnitude of the `n` coordinate because we're just going to squash it to zero anyway.

So it's a few steps to construct the matrix, but hopefully this outlines all the work you have to do to get it.  Then you can just multiply any point `P` by the matrix to project it onto the plane.

eg.:  `P' = MP`

Hopefully you're comfortable enough using a 4x4 matrix, and of course, supplying your vectors that you want to transform in homogenous form, which is a 4-vector with coordinates `(x,y,z,1)`.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks !